# what determines the usernames for gitosis?

Tags: gitosis

When creating a USERNAME.pub file with a public key and adding USERNAME to the config file, is the USERNAME string arbitrary (I can name my gitosis users how I like), or determined by something like the SSH key?

Gitosis tutorials give examples of how to add users to a repo which are very clear (eg http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) but they don't explain this point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be the filename of the key minus the .pub extension. So yes you can name the users whatever you like.

I would like to point out however that gitosis appears to be unmaintained and deprecated by the git community in favor of [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Comment: I'm realizing that now... it's just that the top Google hit for 'hosting git repository' is a Gitosis tutorial :/